# Text highlighter does not change to uppercase

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a simple sqlite3 editor with pyqt5, including a feature (among other rules)  to change reserved words to green, bold, uppercase with a syntax highlighter. Here's a MWC:

```py
...
   self.sql_box = QPlainTextEdit()
   self.highlighter = SqlHighlighter(self.sql_box.document())
...

class SqlHighlighter(QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(SqlHighlighter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rules = []
        ...
        tx_pattern = r"("
        for c in COMMANDS:
            tx_pattern += c + "|"
        tx_pattern = tx_pattern[0:-1] + ")"
        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setForeground(Qt.darkGreen)
        char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
        char_format.setFontCapitalization(QFont.AllUppercase)
        self.rules.append((QRegExp(tx_pattern, cs=Qt.CaseInsensitive), 0, char_format))
        ...

    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        for regexp, idx, chr_fmt in self.rules:
            index = regexp.indexIn(text, 0)
            while index >= 0:
                length = regexp.matchedLength()
                self.setFormat(index, length, chr_fmt)
                index = regexp.indexIn(text, index + length)
        self.setCurrentBlockState(0)
```

While color and weight works correctly it doesn't change to uppercase and I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help, please?

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with pyQt5, but I assume the function you tried that isn't working is `setFontCapitalization(QFont.AllUppercase)`? Where is `char_format` actually applied later?

Comment: @icedwater It's added to a rules lists, which is applied in `highlightBlock`. This follows a common idiom for `QSyntaxHighlighter`s. From the example, we can see that the foreground color and font weight parts of the format are being applied correctly, while the capitalization part is not.

Comment: This was reported as [QTBUG-90840](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-90840) and should be since Qt 5.15.5 and 6.1.1/6.2. The problem with 5.15 is that you may not get the latest version as the official releases for open source stopped with 5.15.2, so you can only get them if you build them on your own (or you use a system that provides custom builds). I'm looking for a way to work around this for previous versions, but I'm not completely sure it is actually possible. If you can upgrade, do it, but consider that users of your program will need an equally updated Qt version too.

Comment: Thanks @musicamante. I'll try to update my Qt version. Now is an alpha version so users are not an issue. Would you like to set your comment as an answer to mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by a reported bug ([QTBUG-90840](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-90840)) which should have been fixed since Qt 5.15.5 and 6.1.1.

Unfortunately, due to the cause of the issue (the way QTextLayout tokenizes its elements), it's extremely difficult if not impossible to work around this with previous versions. While this is probably not an issue for Qt6, it may be for Qt5 if you rely on an existing Qt installation. As far as I know, Qt luckily released an unexpected open-source build for 5.15.6, so you should eventually add that requirement to your program.

Note, though, that changing text case may not be a good idea. Your code didn't show what is the content of `COMMANDS`, but in the rare case the user decides to use a variable/argument that matches any of them (but they still wanted their own caps), it would make the visual result unexpected and undesirable.
In general, word match should always consider the context of the command, since words may have different meaning, and while good practice tells to avoid such words (and syntax may even completely prevent them), you should always consider these aspects.

Finally, a suggestion about the building of `tx_pattern`:

```
tx_pattern = r"(" + "|".join(COMMANDS) + ")"
# eventually:
tx_pattern = rf"({'|'.join(COMMANDS)})"
```

Comment: Thanks @musicamante COMMANDS are the SQLite3 reserved words and i'll add additional rules to avoid the behaviuor you described. Thank you also for the final suggestion.